# Where to store simple state changes in Redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, state

I have a React/Firebase project where I'm trying to integrate Redux. I've set up the fetch quizzes reducer and now I want to update a property in my Firestore. When I've updated the value I get a promise where I dispatch a Redux event https://github.com/cubanpete/quiz/blob/master/src/actions/index.js

I would like to show a simple toaster that says " updated". So in my Quiz component https://github.com/cubanpete/quiz/blob/master/src/components/create/CreateNewQuiz.js I've made a state property "showUpdateLabel" that I would like to change, but I'm confused if "showUpdateLabel" should be in the local state or in the redux store ... and how I create it there? I guess I should set "{showUpdateLabel:true}" in the "UPDATE_QUIZ" somehow. https://github.com/cubanpete/quiz/blob/master/src/reducers/dataReducers.js

Am I wrong?

Comment: `showUpdateLabel` should be in the redux store and once you update it there use `mapStateToProps` to have access to it in your local state.

Comment: Hi Dragos, yes I know that it should be in the Redux store, but how do I create it there?

Comment: So in your `dataReducers` you want to add that `showUpdateLabel` in the initial state of the reducer, and change it based on the action type like you're doing currently. Might be worth reading through this https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Comment: Dragoş, sorry I forgot all about your answer, cause it helped me to move on with my app. So I defined the initial state and then created a new state in stead of mutating it. Thanks man. Can you post a response so I can mark it as answered?